# Better solution to find in list of ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, where-in

Suppose I have an array of id, maybe around 100000 ids. In the case that I cannot create temporary table to do JOIN. The simple solution for me is to do:

```
Product.where(id: ids)
```

This will generate the `WHERE IN` clause which seems to hurt Mysql when the array is big. I wonder if there better solutions to this?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a continuos range, you could try using `BETWEEN` - `Product.where id: 1..100000` will do the trick.

Otherwise, `whole_array_of_ids.each_slice(number_of_ids_mysql_can_handle){ |ids| Product.where(id: ids) }` - multiple queries, but still manageable. [Read about each_slice and more goodies here.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html)

Also, many AR finder methods have `batch_size` param, but it seems it won't help you here, as it will construct the whole query with all the ids and then slap a `LIMIT` at the end.

Comment: In one of my projects, I use the between method. To get the ranges of an Array, you may take a look at https://gist.github.com/Bjoernsen/b38cc5cde2b2c6fc3a0d

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the ids is not a continuous range, but random.

Answer (score 2):

Use find_each to limit the number of records loaded at a time.  find_each defaults to loading 1000 records at a time, but you can adjust that by setting the :batch_size option:

This will query the database for 1,000 records at a time:

```
Product.where(id: ids).find_each do |product|
  # do something with the product
end
```

Or you can change the number of records loaded at one time (how about 50?):

```
Product.where(id: ids).find_each(batch_size: 50) do |product|
  # do something with the product
end
```

Comment: Neither of those help when you are sticking a ton of ids in a IN clause. When you have a query like `select * from posts where id in (1,2,3, ... ,1234567890)`, the database will choke on running the select itself. Oracle, for example, had a hard limit of 1000 items in IN clause. Others would simply become unbearably slow with couple thousand items there.